# Using large font sizes on UISearchBar prevents the text from scrolling

Tags: ios, fonts, uisearchbar

I am changing my UISearchBar's font with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.leftButton;
self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchBar;

//Change font size
UITextField *txfSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txfSearchField setDefaultTextAttributes:@{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:30],
                                           }];
}
```

but it has a side effect of preventing the text from scrolling when the text is longer that the textfield's size.
In the following screenshot I have written "This is a test":
[image: Larger Montserrat makes the typing position stuck]

However if I use "Helvetica" instead of "Montserrat-Regular" the result if fine:
[image: Larger Helvetica works fine]

Edit: Turns out this is a font size issue. The problem happens with any font (even Helvetica) if you set it above a "certain" size. This size is different for every font. I think when the font's height is larger than the textfield's height so that it gets "cropped" this is when the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround I have used a smaller font size, using Montserrat-Regular. As an alternative solution I want to try and increase the textfield's height and see if that works.